# jquery select the next iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html code

```
<div style="width: 1000px;margin: auto" class="cf"> 
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link1">click</div>
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link2">click 2</div>
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link3">click 3</div>
<iframe class='iframe hd' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>

<div class="bo" data-href="../../link1">click</div>
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link2">click 2</div>
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link3">click 3</div>
<iframe class='iframe hd' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>

<div class="bo" data-href="../../link1">click</div>
<div class="bo" data-href="../../link2">click 2</div>
<iframe class='iframe hd' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

I try when i click on any div, the next iframe remove hd class
just and only the next iframe for this specific div i clicked on it

I've tested this selector

`$(".iframe:first")`

not working

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/aa8yK/

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    var iframes = $(this).nextAll("iframe");
    iframes.eq(0).removeClass("hd");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to ensure only the next iframe is selected, not all iframe siblings (the latter would be simple - you could just use `nextAll()`).

Try this

```
$('div').on('click', function() {               
    $(this).next('iframe').add($(this).nextUntil('iframe').next()).removeClass('hd');
});
```

[EDIT] - a much simpler way, and a variation on @Zoltan's answer, would simply be

```
$(this).nextAll('iframe:eq(0)').removeClass('hd');
```